# VBA / Excel Macro - How to Check a Cell for a Specific Formula

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to check the active cell for a specific formula? Here is a simple test I ran that keeps returning "No".

```
sub Test

    'Add formula to a Cell
    Range("J3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"

    If (ActiveCell.Formula = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]") Then
         MsgBox ("Yes")

    Else

         MsgBox ("No")

    End If
End Sub
```

****Update****
This is how I worked it out.

```
Sub Test()

    'Add formula to a Cell
    Range("J3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]"

    'Convert Formula in the Cell to a string
    Dim strFormula As String
    strFormula = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1


    If (strFormula = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]") Then
         MsgBox ("Yes")
    Else
         MsgBox ("No")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: your updated code doesn't have any sense. Check my comment under my answer, please.

Comment: For sure, your `.formula` will never be like `r[]c[]` style.

Comment: Yes, you were right all along. My mistake for using .formula instead of .formulaR1C1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, close to what you have proposed:

```
If ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]+RC[-1]" Then

 'Do Something

End If
```

But keep in mind that comparison is very, very strict- it is case sensitive and space sensitive.

**EDIT due to OP's additional problems**

According to [THIS MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823188%28v=office.14%29.aspx) `Range.FormulaR1C1` property returns Variant type. In my situation I got automatic conversion which makes my code working ok. However, to avoid any problems you could do the conversion in the following way:

```
If CStr(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1) = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]+RC[-1]" Then

 'Do Something

End If
```

Comment: Thank you Kazjaw. It didn't work for me. I posted an update to my original post. (I'm new so not allowed to comment). If you can, please take a look. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user2977498, before `if statement` you could add `debug.print activecell.formular1c1` to see (in immediate window in ide) in which way `.formulaR1C1` is read. Than you could implement it within `if statement`. The problem is, I guess, that you have to make exact comparison here.

Comment: The Immediate Window is displaying it as =R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]

Comment: Hi KazJaw, I found that if you convert the formula to a string and then compare, it works (see above). Thank you so much for taking the time to help me! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code successfully.  I can't see much difference.

```
Private Sub Try_FormulaAsString()

Dim testString As String
testString = Range("J3").FormulaR1C1

If testString = "=R[-1]C+RC[-2]-RC[-1]" Then
    MsgBox "Yes"
Else
    MsgBox "No"
End If

End Sub
```

with cell J3 containing the formula "=J2+H3-I3"

I did notice a difference in the operator for the last term in some of your comments above,
as in -RC[-1] versus +RC[-1]

Is there a reason to use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula`, which would make for easier reading of the formula and reduce the chance of typos in the subroutine?

Comment: Sorry, last comment above was hidden, so did not see that it had been solved.